# Problem with the Firebase database integration to Discord.js bot

Tags: node.js, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, discord.js

I'm making a discord.js v13 bot right now and I want to send the user's messages from the specific channel to my website.
I found a Firebase service as the easiest way to do that.
I watched and repeated everything from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoNm4z-4Bko
But unfortunately, I struggle with the Firebase installation for 16 last hours.

TypeError: firebase.database(...).goOfline is not a function
at Client.

I'm new to programming and I don't have a good base, any of your help is appreciated.
Let me know if I can provide some additional information.

To install Firebase I used
`npm i firebase@8.10.0`

Here is the rest of the code I used on my index.js:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const randomstring = require('randomstring');



const config = {
------------------------------
    CONFIGURATION DATA IS HERE
------------------------------
  };


firebase.initializeApp(config);
const database = firebase.database();



client.on ("message", async message => {
    if (message.author === client.user) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        let ticket = randomstring.generate(7);
        firebase.database().goOnline();
        await database.ref('/Auction4/' + ticket).set({
            Message: message.content,
            User: message.author.username,
            User_ID: message.author.id
        })

        firebase.database().goOfline();
        await client.channels.cache.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`).send(`Thanks, it works!`);
    }

    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```